# Is there a way to work with ODBC by MinGW?

Tags: c++, odbc, mingw

First I tried to download iODBC.

- My MSYS console can't configure it, even if it "INSTALL" document orders to do it, because it has just configure.in, that have to be parsed by autoconf.
- I downloaded GnuWin32 autoconf (2.63) to parse it. But it can't parse, because when I start autoconf in MSYS with path to configure.in, it can't find some files:

  ./autoconf: line 615: C:/PROGRA~2/GnuWin32/autoconf/bin/autom4te: No such file or directory
  ./autoconf: line 615: exec: C:/PROGRA~2/GnuWin32/autoconf/bin/autom4te: cannot execute: No such file or directory

Fun, that autoconf already placed in GnuWin32/bin directory, and autom4te lays near.

- I tried just rename configure.in to configure, but I receive syntax error at first line with "AC_PREREQ(2.59)". Also I found in internet that 2.63 may not work with 2.59, and lost any wish to continue my attempts.
- I also tried to run bootstrap, but it falls with "line 145: --force: command not found".

Then I decide to try unixODBC. I downloaded library 2.3.2 from [home link](http://www.unixodbc.org/), and started to configure it. It was done well.
Then I run "make check". It failed with:

```
iniOpen.c: In function 'iniOpen':
iniOpen.c:401:43: error: 'EOVERFLOW' undeclared (first use in this function)
         ( errno != ENOSPC ) && ( errno != EOVERFLOW ) &&
                                           ^
iniOpen.c:401:43: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
iniOpen.c:402:20: error: 'EWOULDBLOCK' undeclared (first use in this function)
         ( errno != EWOULDBLOCK ))
```

I found that EWOULDBLOCK and EOVERFLOW never met in sources anywhere else. Also I found that it guess take them from MinGW\include\errno.h, where I found all other constaints (such as ENOSPC). Also I found EWOULDBLOCK and EOVERFLOW in boost "cerrno.hpp" and other files with errors. I fixed problem, insterting #ifndef - #define - #endif.

Now I have problem with "ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread" - Linker is trying to link posix threads that are not available at system. I can remove it, but what should I add instead? Or better would be to download and build pthread_win32 from [posix thread for Win link](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/index.html)?

It was built with adding definition for EWOULDBLOCK, EOVERFLOW and configuring with `flag --enable-threads=no`

So, my question is: is there right way to work with ODBC from MinGW WITH threads? If I was moving right way, how to solve those strange (at least because I downloaded releases marked as "stable") troubles?

Comment: Did you try building unixODBC without thread support - there is a configure option for that.

Comment: No, I didn't. Will try to change configure for that. What version of unixODBC will lose without pthread support? I will have to call all methods from one thread/add syncronization, or it will lose something more?

Comment: Yes, unixODBC was built, there is libodbc-2.dll in subdir 'DriverManager', libodbccr-2.dll in subdir 'Cur', and libodbcinst-2.dll in subdir 'odbcinst'. Also some executable, such as slencheck.exe, odbc_config.exe, iusql.exe, odbcinst.exe, dltest.exe, isql.exe.

Comment: I fixed question for current situation.

Comment: Without threads you will lose thread synchronisation i.e., unixODBC will not protect its own data structures. So, if you are not going to need multiple threads to access the same environment or connection then you don't need the thread support anyway.

Comment: Don't you know can I order it to use boost::thread sync system (as I remember it is posix-like), or any other? Or better I should build pthread for windows?

Comment: I don't know but posix-like is going to have to be posix or you'll have to edit unixODBC C code. I'd be absolutely sure you need thread support before going any further and if you do get that far you might need to edit your odbcinst.ini file to tell unixODBC at what level to protect itself - this will depend on the applications you are using and whether it synchronises access to the environment/connection/statement etc or whether unixODBC needs to do it.